# Get 4 bands from sentinel-2 .tiff

Tags: sentinel-2

How can I get an image with 4 channels from https://apps.sentinel-hub.com I mean there are only 3 positions to put only 3 channels.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Your eyes, as well as the physical hardware in your monitor and software that processes it are only available as 3 band combinations for red, green, and blue.

If you want to use more information, i.e. more bands, you have to use or compute indices that combine more than 3 bands.

Comment: I can download separately 4 channels. How can I merge them with color (for every channel) to a new .tiff?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#gdalmerge with Place each input file into a separate band True

Comment: There is no such a thing in 3.22.7-Białowieża edition... :-(

Comment: There is. You can also use "Build Virtual Raster" and then export the output to file

Comment: You can do a 4-band output [with custom script](https://sentinelshare.page.link/9nQN), and then download it as a multi-band tiff using the "Analytical" tab (but unselect the "Clip extra bands" options to get all bands in the output)